# Draw images with CSS vs Images themselves

Tags: css, image

I have just built an application that reads all pixels of an image using Java and then creates a CSS file for drawing that image on the browser.

The fact is that the CSS files are much larger than the images. Suppose if the image occupies 37KB, the CSS occupies 7MB. Thats unacceptably large.

But I have heard somewhere that browsers are slower at requesting images from the server than CSS and also find CSS easy to parse.

Are there still any advantages of that app? Or it was just a waste of time?

Please advice me.

My app works just the way this website works and generates same kinda CSS:

```
http://image2css.alexdoesit.com/
```

Comment: Gosh! Darn It! Just the way this website works. http://image2css.alexdoesit.com/

Comment: the only thing you should be base64-ing in css are icons, you've just wasted your time.

Comment: @MatthewRath What sizes of images do u mean by icons? 60X60

Comment: Images with a very small filesize. I dunno what you read or where but of course images are easier to get from css, because css is locally cached. Therefore if you base64 then images are generated from css memory rather then having to crawl an additional URL going out to the server via an additional HTTP request.

Comment: However the benefit is if you choose to use URL's instead, the images (JPG's, Gifs', SVG, iconfonts) can be cached on their own and have their own expiry times. Meaning the only significant difference for users is when they load a site for the very first time with nothing in cache.

Comment: SO u mean CSS is better for further use if the web pages are cached?

Answer (score 3):

> But I have heard somewhere that browsers are slower at requesting images from the server than CSS and also find CSS easy to parse.

CSS is preferable over images for certain visual effects like rounded corners, shadows, gradients, etc.

But if you intend to emulate "real" pictures (e.g. photographs) using CSS, that's a definitely bad idea. Why?

- **Space:** Consider even the simplest image format like uncompressed 8-bit RGB bitmap. It needs 3 bytes for every pixel (plus some fixed amount of bytes for the whole file). A CSS will probably need considerably more bytes for every pixel.
- **Time:** It is simpler (from computational perspective) to parse and display pixel data than to build a *huge* HTML DOM with styled pseudo-elements.
- **Features:** real images can be additionally processed/changed/enhanced via CSS, like converting an image to greyscale, blurring, etc — see [filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

---

Still, you have accomplished a nice programming exercise:

> I have just built an application that reads all pixels of an image using Java and then creates a CSS file for drawing that image on the browser.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I create a small javascript loop that creates the whole css on the client side rather than creating one big css file directly? I mean, the browser wont have to request the server for all images if this is done by javascript.

Comment: Instead of converting to css you should convert to svg. Then you might have a useful algorithm. Jpg compression is designed to be optimized and you aren't gonna beat it unless you go with a format optimized for images (in this case vectors).

Comment: @Aditya, can you please attach the image you're trying to represent as CSS?

Comment: adirascala.site50.net I have hosted a couple of images on my website. Please have a look. They arent images but CSS drawn graphics.

Comment: @Aditya, sorry, the page is rendered empty (in latest Firefox/Chrome).